# Pulling Unique Combinations of Rows For Min/Max of Column

Tags: sql

Having a roadblock: I have rows with different combinations of variables that leads to a differing output (`Value`)-

Ex)

```
TableTest

TypeID      PopularityID        CriteriaID      ExposureID     Value
10          20                  5               12             2 
10          20                  4               4              0.90
14          20                  2               10             1.21
15          32                  5               8              0.90
18          20                  3               7              51
```

And I wanted to pull only the unique combinations of rows that give me the highest `Value` and the lowest `Value`, also a quick note there might be duplicates in the `Value` column in which case SQL can just pull out all the appropriate rows.

Comment: You can combine ORDER BY (ASC and DESC) and LIMIT 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy peasy

```
select distinct * 
from table 
where value in (select max(value) from table) 
   or value in (select min(value) from table)
```